# How to Write Generic Extension Method to Convert Type in C#

Tags: c#, generics, fluent-interface

I am writing a static guard class/api to validate parameters sent to methods.

Code so far looks like:

```
public static class Guard
{
    public static GuardArgument<T> Ensure<T>(T value, string argumentName)
    {
        return new GuardArgument<T>(value, argumentName);
    }

    public static T Value<T>(this GuardArgument<T> guardArgument)
    {
        return guardArgument.Value;
    }

    // Example extension method
    public static GuardArgument<T> IsNotNull<T>(this GuardArgument<T> guardArgument, string errorMessage)
    {
        if (guardArgument.Value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(guardArgument.Name, errorMessage);
        }

        return guardArgument;
    }
}
```

It can be used as so:

```
public void Test(IFoo foo) {

     Guard.Ensure(foo, "foo").IsNotNull();
}
```

Circumstances now require that I need to cast to concrete types from a supplied interface. Don't ask why, I just need to!

I want to add an `As` extension method to `GuardArgument` to do this, something like:

```
public static GuardArgument<TOut> As<TOut, TIn>(this GuardArgument<TIn> guardArgument, Type type)
        where TOut : class
    {
        // Check cast is OK, otherwise throw exception

        return new GuardArgument<TOut>(guardArgument.Value as TOut, guardArgument.Name);
    }
```

I don't much like the syntax though. I want to be able to use the class as follows:

```
 Foo foo = Guard.Ensure(foo, "foo")
             .As(typeof(Foo))
             .IsNotNull()
             .Value();
```

**I'm not sure how to write the extension method to allow this syntax though.**  I realise I can use the existing fluent API as:

```
 Foo foo = Guard.Ensure(foo as Foo, "foo")
             .IsNotNull()
             .Value();
```

but I don't like this from a readability perspective.

Comment: `Foo foo = Guard.Ensure(foo as Foo, "foo")` will never compile. At least one of the small `foo` variables must have a different name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get this syntax:

```
Foo foo = Guard.Ensure(foo, "foo")
          .As<Foo>()
          .IsNotNull()
          .Value();
```

The trick is to ditch the `TIn` type param. It's not used in the `As()` method and bloats the API when type inference can't be used due to `TOut`. To be able to do that without getting `As()` suggested on all types you have to implement a new, non-generic interface for your `GuardArgument<>` class:

```
interface IGuardArgument 
{ 
  object Value { get; }
  strign Name { get; }
}

public class GuardArgument<T> : IGuardArgument
{
  // Explicit implementation to hide this property from
  // intellisense.
  object IGuardArgument.Value { get { return Value; } 

  // Rest of class here, including public properties Value and Name.
}
```

Now you can write the `As()` method with only one generic param:

```
public static GuardArgument<TOut> As<TOut>(this IGuardArgument guardArgument)
    where TOut : class
{
    // Check cast is OK, otherwise throw exception

    return new GuardArgument<TOut>(guardArgument.Value as TOut, guardArgument.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Introduce an IGuardArgument interface which GuardArgument{T} implements. Then you can remove TIn from the As extension method and remove the Type parameter.
Signature:

```
public static GuardArgument<TOut> As(this IGuardArgument guardArgument);
```

Usage:

```
Guard.Ensure(foo, "foo").As<Foo>().IsNotNull()
```